# What does "debased area" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> The copper archer type may be the variety found in Merv regions, and
>   the Merv-Herat is about the only place where they could be assigned.
>   Sanabares, like the Gondophares group, minted coins in the ***'debased
>   area'*** which include imitation coinage of Hermaios from the Kabul
>   Valley, the Gandhara coinage (after Azilises), and southern Arachosia. (Sanabares and the Gondophares Dynasty - K. WALTON DOBBINS)

([Source](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/42664548?uid=3739920&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106329281251))

What does "debased area" mean?

Comment: Could you include a link to your source?

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/42664548?uid=2134&uid=4582195357&uid=3738280&uid=4582195367&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=4582195357&uid=60&sid=21106752830653

Comment: See, the source gives even more context, which makes it easier to answer. So please try to always include a link. This also allows folks to double-check if the source is correct because sometimes they are wrong (for example: contain misprints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly dense academic writing, and a full answer would probably require reading other things the author has published to see if they have defined 'debased area' more clearly in previous works, however:

I believe "debased area" here is a reference to a specific, historical region where [debased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debasement) coins were produced. A debased coin is one which has its value reduced, often by reducing the amount of precious metal it contains.

[Sanabares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanabares_of_Parthia) was a king, and during his reign coins were minted (produced) in this area, just as they were during the rule of the Gondophares dynasty.

These "debased" coins include imitations of:

(coins of) Hermaios from the Kabul Valley
the Gandhara coinage (after Azilises)
(coins of) southern Arachosia

Why "debased area" rather than specifying a place like "the Merv-Herat"? Possibly because the precise location or correct name is not known, only that there was a common location where these imitation coins were produced.

Comment: +1 I think that's correct, given the context. Also see the source document if you haven't already.

Comment: @pazzo Clicked through but can only see the first page, so I don't know if it's properly defined later on.

Comment: Given it's about coinage, I don't see any other likely meaning.